# After change value with jquery I cant select this value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem with this code: Where I am changing value of eache option and after I want to show or hide div depending on value.

But after changing value of options I cant select in jQuery that value.

```
$("#form1 > select > option:not(:first), #form7 > select > option:not(:first)").each(function() {
$(this).attr('value',$(this).text());
});


$('#frmdocumentsForm-r1').on('change',function(){
    if($(this).val()=='AAA'){
        $('#form2own').show();
    } else {
        $('#form2own').hide();
    }
});
$('#frmdocumentsForm-r7').on('change',function(){
    if($(this).val()=='BBB'){
        $('#form8own').show();
    } else {
        $('#form8own').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$("#form1 > select > option:not(:first), #form7 > select > option:not(:first)").each(function() {
   var textValue = $(this).text().trim();
   $(this).val(textValue);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

trim your text to remove the spaces from it, and then try as

```
$("#form1 > select > option:not(:first), #form7 > select > option:not(:first)").each(function() {
     $(this).val($.trim($(this).text()));
});
```